# Issue with Vue.js debugging messages

Tags: javascript, debugging, vue.js, vuejs2

I have build an web application using Vue.js v2.5.1 for the front-end. The application works well generally, but when there is a problem, the error messages that get thrown only reference the vue.js code itself rather than the parts of my code (I assume something in my templates) that are no doubt the actual source of the problem.

Here is an example:

```
Error in nextTick: "NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 
'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a 
child of this node."
warn @ vue.js?v=1:491
logError @ vue.js?v=1:600
globalHandleError @ vue.js?v=1:595
handleError @ vue.js?v=1:584
(anonymous) @ vue.js?v=1:735
nextTickHandler @ vue.js?v=1:685
vue.js?v=1:604 DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 
'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.
at Object.insertBefore (https://mywebsite.com/js/vendor/vue.js?v=1:5138:20)
at updateChildren (https://mywebsite.com/js/vendor/vue.js?v=1:5628:48)
at patchVnode (https://mywebsite.com/js/vendor/vue.js?v=1:5695:41)
at updateChildren (https://mywebsite.com/js/vendor/vue.js?v=1:5592:21)
at patchVnode (https://mywebsite.com/js/vendor/vue.js?v=1:5695:41)
at updateChildren (https://mywebsite.com/js/vendor/vue.js?v=1:5592:21)
at patchVnode (https://mywebsite.com/js/vendor/vue.js?v=1:5695:41)
at updateChildren (https://mywebsite.com/js/vendor/vue.js?v=1:5592:21)
at patchVnode (https://mywebsite.com/js/vendor/vue.js?v=1:5695:41)
at updateChildren (https://mywebsite.com/js/vendor/vue.js?v=1:5592:21)
```

How can I use this to get to the source of the problem? I have tried using Vue devtools, but all the dev tools show is a list of all my Vue components, the events pane is always empty whatever I do.Whats worse is that when this error occurs, then the whole application grinds to a halt (but the vue data all looks ok still).

Answer (score 6):

If you are doing conditional rendering on an element in an template that is being embedded somewhere and you are using `v-if` try to use `v-show` instead.

i.e.

```
<template>

<div id="remote">
  <span v-show="disable===true" v-on:click="enableInput"> {{account_company_name}} </span>

  <div v-show="disable===false">
    <Span><i>Tip: Press Enter to save</i></Span>
  <input  
type="text" 
  v-model.lazy="account_company_name"
  v-on:keyup.enter="disableInput">
  </div>

</div>
</template>
```

Comment: I agree this works, but why?  In my case the conditional rendering is in a template in a sub component without a Vue Router view. but I don't understand why that nesting would affect it since I did not see this issue when using a dynamic component.

Answer (score 0):

Found this error too, pushing a route change inside a mutation when the state change wasn't completed. Wrapping the route change push in `Vue.nextTick()` solved it.

Answer (score 0):

i had this error before.

in my project ,i figure out that when i deleting some element from dom and then refreshing the dom this error occur, actually i delete a record which was a tr element from vuetable and then refresh that vuetable .after this proccess my vuetable didnt work for me and your error appeared in my console so i decided delete my tr with another way!

So if you are working with dom, choose another way .
for exmple if you are using v-if try v-show !!
or if you are using this code

```
event.target.closest("tr").remove()
```

try another way.